# add different background-image to elements from json array

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, json

Everything is working, but when I want to add `background-image`, to different elements, it's just putting last image from array, and set css backgorund to all of them with that last image.

```
$.get('con.php',function(data) {
    var data = JSON.parse(data);
    for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var div  = "<div class='nemkec-dev' id='"+data[i].id+"'>"+"<h1>"+ data[i].text+"</h1>"+"<p>"+
        data[i].text2+"</p>"+"<img src='images/"+data[i].image+"'/>"+"</div>";
        $('body').append(div);
        var image = data[i].image;
    }
    $.each(data, function(i, dat) {
        $('.nemkec-dev').css('background-image','url(images/'+dat.image+')');  
    });
```

It shows image as element. But, when I want to set css rule it's not working.
Just appending `last-image` to all for background.

Comment: Can you post example `data` and make it working snippet? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Why are you creating image elements wrapped in divs that are having their backgrounds set to the same image!? :/ As stated, the goal is not clear here.

Comment: The last image is set to all of the elements because your selector `'.nemkec-dev'` matches all of the elements. Each iteration every element is set, and the last one is the one which remains.

Comment: the last `$.each(...` you loop through data table and setting all the `.nemkec-dev` background to the same image. Eventually it will be the last image (set to all of them).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When creating `var div` you can create an inline style `var div = "<div style='background-image: url(images/"+data[i].image+")'...`

Comment: Or if he want to separate them use this instead. `$(div).appendTo('body').css('background-image','url(images/'+data[i].image+')');`. Inside the loop of course.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you want to iterate over `$('.nemkec-dev')` elements. What you are doing now is iterating over background images and setting background image for all of `.namkec-dev` divs at once. So natural outcome is that after this script ends you have all `.nemkec-dev` elements with the last background image.

You can go with **Michael Coker** solution and use them in line with other variables, or do something like this:

```
var i = 0;
$('.nemkec-dev').each(function() {
  $(this).css('background-image', data[i].image);
  i++;
});
```

Comment: What would be the value of `i`?

Comment: It's worth noting that this will generate inline styles, too.

Comment: @MichaelCoker Yeah, you are completly right. By inline I meant to use them while creating div with html code.